# Question regarding the alternating series test for $\sum_{n} b_n$

Tags: calculus

Let $\{b_n\}=(-1)^n a_n$, or $(-1)^{n+1}a_n$, with $a_n>0$. In general it is assumed that the sequence of $\{a_n\}$ terms is positive, $\lim a_n =0$, and $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing. My question here is that why do we need $\{a_n\}$ decreasing? Doesn't $a_n > 0$ and $\lim a_n =0$ imply that the sequence is eventually decreasing, and thus that $\sum_n b_n$ converges?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Try $a_{2n}=1/n$ and $a_{2n-1}=1/(n+1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider something like
$$
b_n = (-1)^n \frac{3+(-1)^n}{n}
$$Clearly $b_n=(-1)^n a_n$, with $a_n$ positive and convergent to zero. However $a_n$ is not decreasing and $\sum_n b_n$ diverges, because the two negatives form a divergent harmonic series.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$ given by $a_n=1/n$ if $n$ is odd, and $a_n=e^{-n}$ if $n$ is even. Then we have $a_n>0$ and $a_n\rightarrow 0$, yet $a_n$ is not eventually decreasing.